# How to fix voltage divider that drops more voltage than expected?

Tags: arduino, hacking, smoke-sensor

I'm not sure if I stated the question correctly, but here are some details.

I want to hack Ikea smoke sensor that has a controller designated as CS2105GO-S12 (also known as MC145010). It has aa T4 contact, that outputs smoke sensor signal (HIGH (9V) when it's on, and LOW (0V) if smoke detected).

Now I want to feed this data into an Arduino-compatible Wemos D1 Mini controller, but afraid it will get fried with the 9V signal.

So I need a voltage divider for which I used 170K worth of resistors on one side and 100K resistors for the ground.
Here is the catch, I can't measure voltage across T4 and Ikea sensor ground (battery -), and voltage divider connected to it also does not work.

What should I do?

**EDIT**

Sorry for the chaotic question.

Looks like I found another T12 contact on the sensor board, which serves as the common ground and I can connect voltage divider to it.

**EDIT 2**

So I built the circuit.

Disregard HEF4543 - it's a substitute for Smoke Sensor board.

[image]

Before I hooked the contact from Wemos D2 to A1 it was measuring 3.3V, but after I hooked up D2 to it, it is 1.6V.

Input mode is `INPUT`, no pullup.

Sketch:

```
#define BLYNK_TEMPLATE_ID "****"
#define BLYNK_DEVICE_NAME "Garage Temperature and Smoke Sensor ESP8266"
#define BLYNK_AUTH_TOKEN "****"

#define BLYNK_PRINT Serial
#define APP_DEBUG
#define BLYNK_FIRMWARE_VERSION        "0.1.0"

#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <BlynkSimpleEsp8266.h>
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>

#define SMOKE_PIN D2
#define TEMP_PIN D1

char ssid[] = "***";
char pass[] = "***";

long current = 0L;
long lastDhtCheck = 0L;
long lastSmokeCheck = 0L;

int CHECK_INTERVAL = 60*60*1000;

BlynkTimer myTimer;

OneWire oneWire(TEMP_PIN);
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);
float Celcius = 0;

int ledVal = LOW;

void tempEvent()
{
  sensors.requestTemperatures(); 
  Celcius = sensors.getTempCByIndex(0);
  Blynk.virtualWrite(V1, Celcius);
  Serial.println("Temperature " + (String) Celcius);

  Blynk.logEvent("temperature", Celcius);
  if (Celcius > 60) {
    Blynk.logEvent("temperature_rising", "3D printer Temp " + (String)Celcius);
  }
}

void smokeEvent() {
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, ledVal);
  ledVal = !ledVal;

  int smokePresent = digitalRead(SMOKE_PIN);
  Serial.println("Smoke detector " + (String) smokePresent);
  if (smokePresent == LOW) {
    tempEvent();
    Blynk.logEvent("smoke", "SMOKE");
    Serial.println("SMOKE detected");
  }
  Blynk.virtualWrite(V3, smokePresent);
}


void setup()
{
  pinMode(SMOKE_PIN, INPUT);
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(SMOKE_PIN, LOW);
  // Debug console
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("START");
  sensors.begin();

  myTimer.setInterval(1*1000L, smokeEvent);
  myTimer.setInterval(60*1000L, tempEvent);
  
  Blynk.begin(BLYNK_AUTH_TOKEN, ssid, pass);  
}

void loop()
{
  Blynk.run();
  myTimer.run();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying. Are you saying that when you apply your voltmeter to T4 ***with*** a modified system, that it *"does not work?"* By this, do you mean that your voltmeter no longer reads either 0 V or 9 V? Or what, exactly? Your last paragraph lost me.

Comment: You must have a common connection for a voltage divider to work. If you want to keep the two sides isolated, use a an optoisolator, which also neatly solves the voltage level issue. If the sending side is battery powered (I assume it is), you should have it so the opto is normally unpowered, and only powered when the exceptional case is sensed.

Comment: A basic EE knowledge says that you need at least two wires if you wan't to make a closed circuit.  We have no idea what's a T4 contact and Ikea sensor, unless you describe it. But there is more , a voltage divider with 270k may be to high resistance to measure something, but this is just my thought.

Comment: Please add a basic sketch to your question, showing the detector power and signal pins, the Arduino input and GND pins, and your resistors.  "An Engineer don't take a dump, son, without a schematic."

Answer (score 2):

> I can't measure voltage across T4 and Ikea sensor ground (battery -), and voltage divider connected to it also does not work.

Then your plan won't work. The T4 test point is supposed to be tied to the I/O pin of the controller, pin 7. In normal mode this pin can be an input or an output. I can't tell how it's configured from the datasheet. And your version of the sensor may not have that test point wire to pin 7. Revisions happen all the time without notice to the consumer.

If you can't measure a voltage high between test point and ground, or there is no continuity between test point and pin 7 of the controller, then there is nothing simple that can be done. If pin 7 is connected and acts like an output you could solder to it directly.

An optocoupler is probably best.

Comment: I agree with this suggestion, an optocoupler will allow you to have the signal in whatever reference you want and after that you can change the level as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

The cheap and easy way to do this is with a transistor:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcozRT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The [datasheet of the MC145010](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MC145010.pdf) says pin 7 goes high when smoke is detected.  It also says that pin 14 is the ground of the circuit (connected to the "-" terminal of the 9V battery.)

The transistor circuit will invert the signal.  Low is "smoke detected," high is "no smoke."

Program the WEMOS D2 pin as an input with pull up.  The transistor will pull it low when there's smoke.

---

You can use pretty much any NPN transistor for Q1.  A 2N2222, a 2N3904, pretty much any small NPN transistor will be fine.  Whatever you've got at hand.

Comment: Thank you! From what I see now, I have HIGH for "no smoke, device online", and LOW for "smoke or device offline"